# Indexing tool "Populate Solr Managed Schema" missing

Tags: solr

I am currently trying to migrate some indexes and was looking at the [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/solr-managed-schemas.html). It seems like there should be an option "[Populate Solr Managed Schema](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/image/15c614ad9225c4.png)" in the control panel.

However, in my Sitecore 9.1 control panel that option is missing. I only see "Indexing Manager" under the INDEXING category.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Which search provider did you set? Can you check the value of "search:define"?

Comment: @Gatogordo just checked it: `<add key="search:define" value="Solr" />`

Comment: You can also populate the schema from the admin page, just try this and see whether you get HTTP 200.
http://your-domain/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all

Comment: @Gobinath Thanks that's helpful, but I am still wondering why is missing. Something must be wrong?

Comment: It's PaaS or IaaS instance? If PaaS, which search provider?

Comment: I'm using Sitecore 9.0.1 and I'm facing the same Issue. did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Julius Did you get a solution? I also got the same issue.